# Signing messages using Apache CXF's JAX-RS implementation

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, jks

I have a .jks file and I need to sign a message using JAX-RS. I was using apache-cxf's rest implementation. I have gone through the **apache cxf** site for signing messages using **jax-rs**, but I didn't get clear idea on that.

Coding:

```
    String keystr = "src/main/resources/keystore.jks";                  
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());            
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystr );
        keyStore.load(fis, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("", KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        SSLContext  sslCtxt= SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keyStore).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConn = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtxt, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConn ).build();

        HttpGet getReq = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/xyz?sss=abc");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getReq );

         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          if (entity != null) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));           
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think the jax rs documentation of cxf is not that bad(http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-xml-security.html). Could you please provide more information where do you get errors/where do you have problems with the documentation?

Comment: Maybe my english is too bad, but I don't understand "which is secured one". However maybe you find some usefull information in the example section of cxf http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/

Comment: I think when you say "I need to consume a webservice" you want to implement the server side, so you could take a look into the serverconfig.xml. This are only examples, you could also do this configuration programatically, follow the instructions of the cxf documentation http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: Please do not deface your post by trying to delete all the content. It is still in the edit history, and will most likely be rolled back. If you have a very serious reason for your action, please flag for a moderator attention, and possibly something can be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and easiest way add http conduit  using namespace `xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"` to your cxf confgiuration file and load jks file. Be careful about the `name="*.http-conduit"` this applies to all outgoing cxf request. you can tweak to your specific url based on need. For details refer [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport)

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
            <http:tlsClientParameters>
                <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${'ssl.keystorepassword'}">
                    <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${'ssl.keystorepassword'}"
                        file="${'ssl.keystorefile')}" />
                </sec:keyManagers>
                <sec:trustManagers>
                    <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${'ssl.truststorepassword'}"
                        file="${'ssl.truststorefile'}" />
                </sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
                </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            </http:tlsClientParameters>
            <http:authorization>
            </http:authorization>
            <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" />
    </http:conduit>
```

Comment: What ever the code you are using is not cxf web client. its apache http client, not sure about the configuration